# Looping requests using urllib

Tags: python, urllib

Looking for some help with regards to sending multiple looping requests to an online api using urllib.

I'm currently working on some python scripts for work to help us identify potential line of sight issues between our radars and proposed wind turbine developments.

The last piece of the puzzle is creating an elevation profile so we can quickly assess which turbines are likely to be an issue and which are not.  I have been attempting to maniupulate the existing code found [here](https://www.geodose.com/2018/03/create-elevation-profile-generator-python.html) to interrogate the OpenElevation API for which I have signed up and have a key.

Previously I had attempted to parse through elevation data extracted from a GIS software as a .xyz file.  This however was time consuming and the extracted elevations were only accurate to 3 decimal places.

The code reads from the `radars.csv` and then pairs that radar with each individual turbine, sending requests for line of sight.  Unfortunately I think I must be bombarding the server as I get repeated `connection forcibly closed` or `gateway time-out` errors returning.

```
import csv
import math
import urllib.request
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##Extract data from radar and turbine csv files##
with open('readfiles/radars.csv') as csvfile: #get radar data
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        #START-END POINT
        P1=[]
        P2=[]

        radarlong=(float(row[0])) #convert to correct data types
        radarlat=(float(row[1]))
        radarheight=(int(row[2]))
        radarname=(row[3])

        P1.append(radarlong)
        P1.append(radarlat)

        ##Open windfarm csv and store variables
        with open('readfiles/windfarms.csv') as csvfile: #get windfarm data
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in reader:
                windfarmlong = (float(row[0])) #convert to correct data types
                windfarmlat = (float(row[1]))
                windfarmheight = (int(row[2]))
                windfarmname = (row[3])

                P2=[windfarmlong, windfarmlat]

                print(P1, P2)

                #NUMBER OF POINTS
                s=100
                interval_lat=(P2[0]-P1[0])/s #interval for latitude
                interval_lon=(P2[1]-P1[1])/s #interval for longitude

                #SET A NEW VARIABLE FOR START POINT
                lat0=P1[0]
                lon0=P1[1]

                #LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE LIST
                lat_list=[lat0]
                lon_list=[lon0]

                #GENERATING POINTS
                for i in range(s):
                    lat_step=lat0+interval_lat
                    lon_step=lon0+interval_lon
                    lon0=lon_step
                    lat0=lat_step
                    lat_list.append(lat_step)
                    lon_list.append(lon_step)

                #HAVERSINE FUNCTION
                def haversine(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2):
                    lat1_rad=math.radians(lat1)
                    lat2_rad=math.radians(lat2)
                    lon1_rad=math.radians(lon1)
                    lon2_rad=math.radians(lon2)
                    delta_lat=lat2_rad-lat1_rad
                    delta_lon=lon2_rad-lon1_rad
                    a=math.sqrt((math.sin(delta_lat/2))**2+math.cos(lat1_rad)*math.cos(lat2_rad)*(math.sin(delta_lon/2))**2)
                    d=2*6371000*math.asin(a)
                    return d

                #DISTANCE CALCULATION
                d_list=[]
                for j in range(len(lat_list)):
                    lat_p=lat_list[j]
                    lon_p=lon_list[j]
                    dp=haversine(lat0,lon0,lat_p,lon_p)/1000 #km
                    d_list.append(dp)
                d_list_rev=d_list[::-1] #reverse list


                #CONSTRUCT JSON
                d_ar=[{}]*len(lat_list)
                for i in range(len(lat_list)):
                    d_ar[i]={"latitude":lat_list[i],"longitude":lon_list[i]}
                location={"locations":d_ar}
                json_data=json.dumps(location,skipkeys=int).encode('utf8')

                try:
                    #SEND REQUEST 
                    url="https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup"
                    response = urllib.request.Request(url,json_data,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
                    fp=urllib.request.urlopen(response)

                    #RESPONSE PROCESSING
                    res_byte=fp.read()
                    res_str=res_byte.decode("utf8")
                    js_str=json.loads(res_str)
                    #print (js_mystr)
                    fp.close()

                    #GETTING ELEVATION 
                    response_len=len(js_str['results'])
                    elev_list=[]
                    for j in range(response_len):
                        elev_list.append(js_str['results'][j]['elevation'])

                    #BASIC STAT INFORMATION
                    mean_elev=round((sum(elev_list)/len(elev_list)),3)
                    min_elev=min(elev_list)
                    max_elev=max(elev_list)
                    distance=d_list_rev[-1]

                    #PLOT ELEVATION PROFILE
                    base_reg=0
                    plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
                    plt.plot(d_list_rev,elev_list)
                    plt.plot([0,distance],[min_elev,min_elev],'--g',label='min: '+str(min_elev)+' m')
                    plt.plot([0,distance],[max_elev,max_elev],'--r',label='max: '+str(max_elev)+' m')
                    plt.plot([0,distance],[mean_elev,mean_elev],'--y',label='ave: '+str(mean_elev)+' m')
                    plt.fill_between(d_list_rev,elev_list,base_reg,alpha=0.1)
                    plt.text(d_list_rev[0],elev_list[0],"P1")
                    plt.text(d_list_rev[-1],elev_list[-1],"P2")
                    plt.xlabel("Distance(km)")
                    plt.ylabel("Elevation(m)")
                    plt.grid()
                    plt.legend(fontsize='small')
                    plt.show()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(str(e))
```

Can someone advise me on a way I can go about interrogating a remote API efficiently when trying to batch process a large amount of data? I also apologies if I'm missing something basic or if I'm going about this in the most inefficient way possible - I'm new to Python and coding in general so I'm trying to learn as I go.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is too many request to server. You already send a list of coordinates to 'https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup'.

I see the only way to increase request count.

1. Group your data in one request
2. Use `proxy` in `requests`
   You can use free proxies from https://free-proxy-list.net/ or simular url.

```
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
}

requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

3. Use delay between request. It helps to bypass the DDoS defence

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: That is great advice. Ill read up on how to group requests and the proxies and I will let you know how I get on!

Comment: It worked, thank you.  It would appear from other users that the API server is pretty much inundated with requests which explains why Im often getting 5xx errors returning.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it